# C# with WPF - Creating a grid of buttons resizable at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to implement the following: I have an empty window in the beginning with 3 buttons. When I click a button, I want to generate `Size*Size` buttons in the window. For button 1, `Size=6`, for button 2 `Size=8` and for button 3 `Size=0`, so I thought I'd create a `UniformGrid` and bind its size to `Size`, so I can change the number of buttons present. Initially, `Size` would be 0, so no buttons can be seen, then when `Size` changes, the buttons appear. This, however, doesn't work. I'm trying:

```
<Window x:Class="project.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="500" Width="700">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Menu Grid.Column="1" Margin="38,0,187,430" Background="White">
      <MenuItem Header="Level 1" FontFamily="Roboto" Height="32" Width="65"
                Command="{Binding Lvl1Command}"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Level 2" FontFamily="Roboto" Height="32" Width="65"
                Command="{Binding Lvl2Command}"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Level 3" FontFamily="Roboto" Height="32" Width="65"
                Command="{Binding Lvl3Command}"/>
    </Menu>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Size}" Columns="{Binding Size}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button Focusable="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
                  Width="30" Height="25" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold">
          </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Size` is initially 0, `Lvl1Command` changes Size to 6, `Lvl2Command` to 8 etc. `Fields` is just a data structure storing some properties that will affect the style of the button. How could/should I modify this so that when Size changes, the number of appearing Buttons does too? Thank you!

**EDIT**
In the ViewModel constructor:

```
Lvl1Command = new DelegateCommand(param => { SetUpGame(MLModel.Level.Easy); });
Lvl2Command = new DelegateCommand(param => { SetUpGame(MLModel.Level.Medium); });
Lvl3Command = new DelegateCommand(param => { SetUpGame(MLModel.Level.Hard); });
```

And `SetUpGame()` looks like this (`Field` included):

```
private void SetUpGame(MLModel.Level level)
{
    UpCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => { _model.MoveUp(); RefreshTable(); });
    DownCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => { _model.MoveDown(); RefreshTable(); });
    LeftCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => { _model.MoveLeft(); RefreshTable(); });
    RightCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => { _model.MoveRight(); RefreshTable(); });

    // időzítő létrehozása
    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
    _timer.Start();

    _model.SetLevel(level);
    _model.NewGame();            
    Fields = new ObservableCollection<MLField>();
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < _model.Table.Size; i++)
    {
        for (Int32 j = 0; j < _model.Table.Size; j++)
        {
            Fields.Add(new MLField
            {
                Text = _model.Table[i, j],
                X = i,
                Y = j,
                Number = i * _model.Table.Size + j
            });
        }
    }
    RefreshTable();
}
```

And then `Size`:

```
public Int32 Size { get { return _model.Size; } }
```

Comment: can you please show your viewModel code for `Lvl1Command`, `Lvl2Command`, `Lvl3Command`, `Fields`, `Size`?

Comment: @ASh added the code you requested! :)

Comment: @ASh the method you're talking about should be called `NotifyPropertyChanged` (just quite as the interface name!) or `RaisePropertyChanged`... `OnPropertyChanged` is a name that I see more suitable as event _handler_, non as event _raiser_...

Comment: @ASh yeah I know what you're talking about, but it's a matter of readability. A little philosophical question, nonetheless... Anyway, read the code as an English sentence: when you encounter "OnPropertyChanged", you would read it as "On the change of this property, do this and this". "OnPropertyChanged" recall the _consequence_ of a PropertyChanged event. So, the _handler_ of it. But this is not what you want in the setters on the properties: there, you want to _raise_ the event, not to _react_ to an _already raised_ event, right? Maybe it's only an hair-splitting problem, anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewModel must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Add this code:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Then, if you want to raise notifications for changes on the `Size` property, write it this way:

```
public int Size
{
    get { return _Size; }
    set
    {
        if (_Size != value)
        {
            _Size = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
private int _Size;
```

Also, the `Fields` collection is initially null, and when you instantiate it in the `SetupGame`, no notification is raised so the View is still bound to the null reference. You have 2 options:

1) **initialize the Fields collection in the constructor**. This way, when the ViewModel is passed to the View, the collection is ready to be bound to the `ItemsControl`. It is not necessary to fill the collection in the constructor, just to instantiate it.

2) **implement the Fields property in the same way the Size is**:

```
public ObservableCollection<MLField> Fields
{
    get { return _Fields; }
    set
    {
        if (_Fields != value)
        {
            _Fields = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
private ObservableCollection<MLField> _Fields;
```

This way, you can set a new instance of the collection every time you want, and the ItemsControl binding will update consequently.